# where should I place conjunction in the sentence?

Tags: conjunctions

I have a problem with the placement of conjunctions in a sentence. (Especially when I am writing an academic article.)

In many articles, writers place the conjunctions in the middle of sentence.

For exp.; It cannot, however, be inferred from the fact that.. or

However, it cannot be inferred from the fact that...

When should I place them in the beginning of sentence/in the middle of sentence?

I am confused about it.  It is also applicable for therefore, furthermore, otherwise etc.

Comment: I feel the need for an example.  You might have been trying to provide one with "For exp.; For the rest, however, no remedy i to be found in this way.. or It cannot, however, be inferred from the the fact that.." but honestly I can't follow that bit at all.

Comment: I am sorry for my writing. I am not good at it. I have a problem to place some conjunctions in the sentence. For example I have learned at school that I should use "however" in the beginning of sentence. But now when I read an academic article, nobody use "however" in the beginning. They are using in the middle. And I do not understand it how should I use them. It is also applicable for therefore, furthermore, otherwise etc. I hope I could explain.

Comment: I understand.  I'm trying to provide feedback.  I understood the rest but you lost me here.  Can you provide a clear example of a complete sentence where you are unsure where the conjunction should go?  Please edit the question and place it there rather than here as a comment.

Comment: I edited it. I hope I provide some clarity. Thank you.

Comment: After looking at the source I think the problem was that stackexchange was eating your whitespace.  You originally meant for "or" to split that bit into two different lines.

Comment: I am quite new. I tried to fix it. Many thanks for edits.

Comment: @medica thank you I didn't see that.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily write those two examples with however at the beginning:

However, for the rest, no remedy is to be found...
However, it cannot be inferred that..

Putting however in the middle of the sentence creates an interruption  and causes your reader to pause. I think this helps place emphasis on whatever you wrote before the however because it slows the reader down.

Stylistically, its up to you. There's no 'right' answer in this case, you can do either.